# Binding a nullable comboxbox selected value

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

My combobox has an ItemsSource bound to a collection of valid values.  Howerver NULL is also valid.  The difficulty is that if the user selects an item from the combobox, there's no way for them to get back to "null".  There are some workarounds that I can imagine:

1. put some sort of "x" beside the combobox to "delete" the selected value (assign null).
2. manually add a "null" entry to the collection of Items.

I don't like option 1 for a variety of reasons: visuall unappealing, and two confusing to the user, since you don't often see this in the wild.
I don't like option 2, simply out of resentment, as I feel that having to mess with the set of values from the server is an  nfortunate workaround.

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious about binding a combobox selectedvalue to a nullable property.

Comment: Why do you want a null item in your ComboBox?

Comment: I don't want a null item in the combo box, however if NULL is a valid value how does the user select NULL as an option?

Answer (score 0):

When a ComboBox is bound to a collection and the collection has a null value then you will see a blank spot where the null object is. The user can still select this null item.

If you don't want a null object in the list then create a custom ObservableCollection that inherits from ObservableCollection and everytime the user adds/insets an item do a check if its null and if so remove it.